# Getting "sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied" when splitting lines from file and inserting into database

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to import data from a csv file to a existing database, the database has 4 columns called product_id, Firstname, Lastname, Address and this is the code for the csv import;

```
import sqlite3, csv

connection = sqlite3.connect("martin_DB3")
cursor = connection.cursor()

with open("lista.csv","r") as file:
    records = 0
    for i in file:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO DATABASE VALUES (?,?,?,?)", i.split(","))
        connection.commit()
        records += 1
connection.close()
print ("Data has been transfered")
```

But I keep getting the error

> sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 4, and there are 1 supplied.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you had the intention of using `csv` but then you didn't.

You can do something like this and it will work (even if you have missing values in the CSV):

```py
with open("lista.csv", "r") as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for n, r in enumerate(reader):
        t = tuple(r.values())
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO DATABASE VALUES (?,?,?,?)", t)
        connection.commit()
        print(n)
```

BTW: `DATABASE` is not a great name for a `TABLE`

Answer (score 0):

If one line in the file does not contain exactly 3 commas, the expression `i.split(",")` results in a list with a different length than 4.

In your case, the line apparently contained no commas. This may happen, for example, if there are empty lines in the file.

You could test the length of the resulting list before passing it to `cursor.execute` and skip it if the length is not 4. In order to do this, you have to assign it to a variable first:

```py
for i in file:
    values = i.split(",")
    if len(values) != 4:
        continue
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO DATABASE VALUES (?,?,?,?)", values)
```

Comment: You mean the csv file right? The columns are seperated by exactly 3 commas, I'm not sure what that last lines mean, in which I should test the lenght of the resulting list? It's not a list though, it's a database, is that what you mean?

Comment: I mean the list resulting from the expression `i.split(",")` where `i` is one line from the csv file. If the length of that list is not 4, passing it as argument to the query will result in the error you have shown.

Comment: when you say lenght of that list, are you reffering to amount of columns when saying lenght? And how should I write the last expression? I thought that last expression would only work as a function to seperate the columns by ","